# Gifs PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

is it possible to put a GIF or a video in a window using PySimpleGui? I have a code where it shows an image in the first window, where I would like to put an animated gif, I tried some ways but it didn't work.

[sg.Image(filename='2.png')],  #window where I would like to show the gif

```
from asyncore import write
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyautogui 
import time 
import os 
t = time.sleep
gui = pyautogui


os.system('cls') # limpa o terminal
users = ['GUILHERME','GABRIEL','MATHEUS','RAUL','SATO','MAURICE']
workers = ['WORKER01','WORKER02','WORKER03','WORKER04']
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
global values
global hand 

hand= sg.InputText(key ='hand',do_not_clear = True, size =(20,1))
canal = sg.InputText(key ="canal", size =(20,1))
sleep1 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep1", size =(20,1))
sleep2 = sg.InputText(key ="sleep2", size =(20,1))
par = sg.InputText(key ="par", size =(20,1))
perc = sg.InputText(key ="perc", size =(20,1))
usu = sg.Listbox(users, key = 'usu',size = (20,1))
worker = sg.Listbox(workers, key = 'worker', select_mode="",size = (20,1))

layout1 = [

    [sg.Image(filename='2.png')],  #window where I would like to show the gif
    [sg.Text('Bem Vindo Usário, siga o questionamento para identificar seus dados:', size = (50,1))],
    [sg.Text("VALOR DA MÃO?" ,size = (25,1)),hand],
    [sg.Text("CANAL DE TRABALHO?", size = (25,1)),canal],
    [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA LATERAL? " ,size = (25,1)),sleep1],
    [sg.Text("FREQUÊNCIA VERTICAL?" ,size = (25,1)),sleep2],
    [sg.Text("QUAL PAR VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),par],
    [sg.Text("QUAL RANGE VOCÊ QUER?" ,size = (25,1)),perc],
    [sg.Text("QUAL PERFIL?",size =(25,1)),usu],  # SELECT MODE = MULTIPLE PARA SELECIONAR MAIS DE UMA OPÇÃO AO MESMO TEMPO 
    [sg.Text("QUAL WORKER?",size =(25,1)),worker], 
    [sg.Text("QUAL PRAZO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("LONGO","prazo",True,key="longoprazo"),sg.Radio("CURTO","prazo",key="curtoprazo")], # sg.radio são definidas como True or False, então crie uma função 
    [sg.Text("QUAL LADO?",size =(24,1)),sg.Radio("DOWN","lado",True,key="ladodown"),sg.Radio("UP","lado",key="ladoup")],
    [sg.Button("Entrar"), sg.Button("Cancelar")],
    ]

def tratar_lado(): 
    if values['ladodown'] == True: 
        gui.write('DOWN')
    else: 
        gui.write('UP')

def tratar_prazo(): 
    if values['longoprazo'] == True: 
        gui.write('LONGO')
    else: 
        gui.write('CURTO')

def abrir_putty1():
    gui.press('Win');t(0.5);
    gui.write('PUTTY');t(0.5);gui.press('Return');t(1);gui.write('temporario');t(1);gui.press('Return');t(3) #gui.write(values['usu'][0])
    gui.write('batata123');gui.press('Return')    
    
def iniciar():
    gui.press('capslock')
    gui.press('Win');t(0.5); 
    gui.write('PUTTY');t(0.5);gui.press('Return');t(1);gui.write("####");t(1);gui.press('Return');t(2) #gui.write(values['usu'][0])
    gui.write('####');gui.press('Return');
    gui.write('cd');gui.press('tab');gui.write(values['worker'][0]);gui.press('tab');tratar_lado();gui.press('Return');print('A pasta local foi localizada com sucesso...');window.refresh()
    gui.write('nano coloca.tty',interval = 0.3);gui.press('Return');print('Preparando para editar o Putty');window.refresh()
    gui.hotkey('Ctrl','W');gui.write("LIMIT", interval = 0.3);(1);gui.press('Return');t(0.3) #pesquisa LIMIT no nano 
    gui.press('right', presses = 25, interval= 0.1);gui.press('Backspace', presses = 2);gui.write(values["hand"]);print('Primeira mão editada com sucesso...');window.refresh() #Edita a Primeira Mão 
    gui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'W');gui.write('limit.tty', interval = 0.1);t(0.5);gui.press('Return');gui.press('right', presses = 29, interval = 0.1);gui.press('Backspace', presses = 4, interval =0.1) # edita a segunda mão
    t(0.5);gui.write(values["hand"]);t(0.5);print('Segunda mão editada com sucesso...');window.refresh() #inputa a segunda mão e printa 

    gui.hotkey('Ctrl', 'W');t(0.5);gui.write('totordens', interval =0.1);t(0.5);pyautogui.press('Return');t(0.5);gui.press('right', presses = 33, interval= 0.2)
    t(0.5);gui.press('backspace', presses = 1, interval = 0.3);t(0.5);gui.write(values[canal]);print('Canal de trabalho editado com sucesso...');window.refresh()


def janela_acompanhamento(values2): 
    janela_layout =  [ 

            [sg.Text('DILLO BOT - INICIALIZADOR')],
            [sg.Multiline(reroute_stdout=True, size = (90,40))],
            [sg.Button('OK')]]
    janela_acompanhamento = sg.Window("Janela de Acompanhamento", janela_layout)

    while True: 
        event, values = janela_acompanhamento.read(timeout=50)
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Fechar'): 
            break
        elif event == 'Entrar': 
         janela_acompanhamento.read
        elif event == 'OK':
            
            print("PROTOCOLO"+" "+"---->", end="  ");
            print("U:"+values2['usu'][0],end="  ")
            print("W:"+values2['worker'][0], end = " ")
            print("M:"+values2["hand"],end="  ")
            print("P:"+values2["par"],end="  ")
            print("R:"+values2["perc"],end="  ")
            print("C:"+values2["canal"],end="  ")
            print("S1:"+values2["sleep1"],end="  ")
            print("S2:"+values2["sleep2"],end="  ")
            
            window.refresh()    
            print('Bem vindo   '  + values2['usu'][0]+ '.      Prepare um café enquanto o Dillo Inicia!');window.refresh();iniciar()
            
            
window = sg.Window('Dillo Bot', layout1)
while True: 
    event, values = window.read()
    sg.theme('DarkAmber')
    if event in (None, "Quit"):
        break
    if event == 'Cancelar':
        break
    if event == 'Entrar': 
        window.hide()
        janela_acompanhamento(values)
window.close()
```

[window where I would like to show the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cala4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, should reduce your code to only something about your question, not in full code of your project.

Following code demo one way to show the GIF in a window.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Image(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, key='-GIF-')]]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT:
        window['-GIF-'].update_animation(sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, time_between_frames=100)

window.close()
```